# adMob | Smart banner at bottom?

Tags: android, admob, smartbanner

The idea is to put the admob banner at the bottom of the screen I tried with `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` but the banner stand in the middle of the place that it occupies. Currently looks like this: [pic1](http://puu.sh/bSp9f/35f1b9d446.png) And I want to look like this: [pic2](http://puu.sh/bSp9g/2366510a3e.png)

My code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="eu.gabrielatanasov.demoViewer.Home_activity" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

App stuff here

```
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/homeContentLayout"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/adMob_ID" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: oh..try with different height

Comment: What to set for height?

Comment: layout _height attribute in com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.

Comment: I meant wherewithal to replace match_parent?

Comment: ha...replace match_parent with some other static value or wrap_content..

Comment: not working, banner again sitting in the middle, I try and with fill_parent the result is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your layout a little bit, check this out:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeContentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="admobid">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **content_main.xml** file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```